# Computing the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}n\exp(-an^3)\sin(n\theta)$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm trying to compute the infinite sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}n\exp(-an^3)\sin(n\theta),$$ where $a>0$ and $\theta$ are arbitrary real numbers.

The presence of $\sin(n\theta)$ makes the terms oscillate in sign. Additionally, the exponential cubic term makes sure that the terms decay fast as $n$ becomes large. So the sum is definitely finite and should exist.

Unfortunately I have no clue on how to compute the sum. I feel it would be nice if the sum can somehow be converted to an integral, which can then be evaluated. Any thoughts on how to compute the sum?

In response to a question below, I'm not sure if the sum can be exactly computed; it'll be great if the series can be summed. If the sum cannot be exactly computed, I would appreciate if there are clear thoughts on how to convert the sum into an integral. As a side problem, I am interested in finding the leading asymptotic behavior of the sum as $a \rightarrow 0$. My hope is that I would be able to extract this if the sum can be explicitely computed or if the sum can be represented as an integral whose asymptotic behavior for $a \rightarrow 0$ can be tracked.

Comment: Is there a reason to believe there is a closed form?

Comment: There is a closed form for $\sum e^{-an}\sin n\theta.$ But I can’t see why it would be true in your case.

Comment: You need $a>0$ for the series to converge.

Comment: As @Thomas Andrews commented, beside an exponent of $1$, little hope. For this specific case $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\,e^{-an}\,\sin(n\theta)=\frac{\sinh (a) \sin (\theta )}{2 (\cos (\theta )-\cosh (a))^2}$$ and series expansion around $a=0$ would give $$\frac{ \sin (\theta )}{2 (\cos (\theta )-1)^2}a+\frac{ \sin (\theta ) (\cos
   (\theta )+5)}{12 (\cos (\theta )-1)^3}a^3+O\left(a^5\right)$$

Comment: Even the much simpler series $\sum_n e^{\alpha n^2}$ is a [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) and has no especially simpler expression than that (though there are of course beautiful identities at play there). I doubt there is any hope here.